# How to make my variable with queue.poll() value accessible to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, queue

I have a class project, in Java, and I'm using android studio for coding.

The project is rock paper scissors.

Basically, I made a queue containing the names of the enemy.

I `q.poll()` them and gave each a variable with the name **`firstenemy`**, **`secondenemy`**, and **`thirdenemy`**.

In the first game, I want to set my text view as the first enemy. Then, after the user won, it will take the user to the next activity with a similar layout, but with a different enemy name.

Here, I want to set the textview name with the variable **`secondenemy`** from the first game activity.

How can I do that ? Or, is there a way to convert the **`q.poll()`** into a string ?

Sorry for asking (maybe) such a noob question.

This is my code on the first game activity :

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameplay);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();




    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String text = intent.getStringExtra(Page2Activity.EXTRA_TEXT);


    nama = findViewById(R.id.name);
    nama.setText(text);
    q.add("Jackson");
    q.add("Diamante");
    q.add("Borsalino");
    String firstenemy = q.poll();
    String secondenemy = q.poll();
    String thirdenemy = q.poll();
    TextView textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView4.setText(firstenemy);
    winners = findViewById(R.id.winners);
    userresult = findViewById(R.id.userresult);
    enemyresult = findViewById(R.id.enemyresult);
    userresult.setText(text);
    enemyresult.setText(firstenemy);
    userresult2 = findViewById(R.id.userresult2);
    enemyresult2 = findViewById(R.id.enemyresult2);

    rand = new Random();
}
```

Comment: Why are you even adding them to queue?

Comment: the project required us to use data structure, so I used queue, and adding those name to queue is the easiest way for me to implement queue to the project

Comment: ok let me tell you that you are doing the project wrong. When using data structure it means that you have to implement your own data structure. So it's far away from adding them to Queue and polling.  Or else, if u can use existing one, not like you're doiong - at least.

Comment: yes, i do have my own queue code(the one that have enq, deq, peek, etc method)but i think its kinda too complicated for me, and my teacher said it is ok to use the imported queue from java, that's why I use the imported one. why I don't use my own is because I think it is easier to do so.